# Странная задержка у input

Tags: html, css, transition

http://www.studita.tmweb.ru/log.php

При нажатии на кнопку на логотип СТУДИТА меняется цвет, и если обратить внимание на input то модно увидеть **странную задержку**. Помогите её убрать. Или есть идеи почему она появляется?

Comment: Задержки не наблюдаю, опишите подробнее.

Comment: Я вижу задерку. Выложите здесь часть js кода, который меняет цвет.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178988 - тащи код в вопрос

Comment: ребят большое спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При нажатии на логотип вы слишком много в DOM дереве добавляете классов, чтоб поменять только цвета элементов. Достаточно присваивать класс white на родительский элемент, а  все остальные изменения делать через него:

```
.white {backgound-color: #fff;}
.white input {backgound-color: #fff;}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Помог!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так, только `!important` убрать вместе с бесполезными цветами в стилях:

```
.form-control, .form-control input {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```